# How to structure my Users Database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a website that allows users to be different types. Each of these types can do specific things. I am asking if I should set up 1 table for ALL my users and store the types in an enum, or should I make different tables for each type. Now, if the only thing different was the type it would be easy for me to choose only using one table. However, here's a scenario.

The 4 users are A, B, C, D.

User A has data for:

- name
- email

User B has data for:

- name
- email
- phone

User C has data for:

- name
- email
- phone
- about

User D has data for:

- name
- email
- phone
- about
- address

If I were to create a single table, should I just leave different fields null for the different users? Or should I create a whole separate table for each user?

Comment: you may want to add ID as the main field with primary key

Comment: no  create 1 table  and  you can  put nulls  in that columns

Comment: This isn't my real database it was simply a quick example...I do intend on using an ID later on

Answer (score 2):

Much better if you could create a single table for all of them. Though some fileds are *nullable*. And add an extra column (*enum*) for each type of users. If you keep your current design, you will have to use some *joins* and *unions* for the records. (*which adds extra overhead on the server*)

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    ID INT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    phone VARCHAR(50),
    about VARCHAR(50),
    address VARCHAR(50),
    userType ENUM()         -- put types of user here
)
```

Another suggested design is to create two tables, one for user and the other one is for the types. The main advantage here is whenever you have another type of user, you don't have to alter the table but by adding only extra record on the user type table which will then be referenced by the users table.

```
CREATE TABLE UserType
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE users
(
    ID INT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50),
    phone VARCHAR(50),
    about VARCHAR(50),
    address VARCHAR(50),
    TypeID INT,
    CONSTRAINT rf_fk FOREIGN KEY (TypeID) REFERENCES UserType(ID)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Basic database design principals suggest one table for the common elements and additional tables, JOINed back to the base table, for the attributes that are unique to each type of user.

Your example suggests one and only one additional field per user-type in a straightforward inheritance hierarchy.  Is that *really* what the data looks like, or did you simply for the example?  If that's a true representation of your requirements, I might be tempted (for expedience) to use a single table.  But if the real requirements are more complex, I'd bite the bullet and do it "correctly".

Comment: The data was just an example related to one of my problems. It is the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating four tables:

```
Table 1: Name, email
Table 2: Name, phone
Table 3: Name, about
Table 4: Name, address
```

Name is your primary key on all four tables.  There are no nulls in the database.  You're not storing an enumerated type but derive the type from table joins:

```
To find all User A select all records in table 1 not in table 2
To find all User B select all records in table 2 not in table 3
To find all User C select all records in table 3 not in table 4
To find all User D select all records in table 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create tables for different people because this will lead to a bloated database. It's best to create a single table with all the fields you need. If you don't use the field, pass in null values.

Comment: Precisely the opposite is true.  Creating a single table substantially populated by NULLs will bloat the database (and the memory cache) with unnecessary entries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use 1 single table with nullable fields. And a table of something like roles.